# Anime Pegasus film from childhood

Tags: story-identification, anime

I would like to identify a film I used to watch as a child on video tape.

I believe it is anime with a young boy trying to catch a pegasus. He sees it in a clearing of wood and at some point chases it to the top of a tower. I believe the pegasus is white (but my memory maybe fading me).

I was watching it back in approx 1990-1995 however the film maybe much older as I also used to watch the 1975 little mermaid anime at the same time, my gran had these both on video. It was dubbed im pretty sure. The only other thing I can remember is the fascination this young boy had with trying to catch this pegasus.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE, Blondish Girl.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE.  There's not much to go off of with your question right now.  Could you please take a look at the: [How to ask good story-identification questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) section and try and fill out as much as you can about your search?  Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

I wonder if you are recalling the 1978 animated film [*Metamorphoses*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphoses_(1978_film)) (aka *Winds of Change*, with a rearrangement of chapters in the film), which presents number of ancient Greek myths as interpreted by [Ovid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovid) and narrated by [Peter Ustinov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Ustinov)? The film was directed by Takashi Masunaga in Japan, distributed by Sanrio in the US, and bears a definite anime influence in the art style.

There are several scenes where a young protagonist attempts to capture an animal in clearings in the woods during the film, and a few scenes with towers. The scene where [Perseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseus) (presented as a young boy) meets [Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus) occurs more in a cliff-side, cave-ish, and tower-ish location.

The scene with Pegasus begins around the 1:12:48 mark in the *Wind of Change* version (you can watch the film in its entirety):

Here is the movie poster, which also features Pegasus:

[image: Movie poster for the 1978 animated film Metamorphoses]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately it's not the film but I can see that it does match my description so thank you again 

Comment: For what it's worth, the japanese title of the poster reads Hoshi No Orefeusu (?Orpheus of Star?) Which seems to match the imagery of a male character followed by a female along a long path.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu Yes! And Orpheus and Eurydice's tale was another chapter of the film. That's Orpheus with his lyre on his back in the still-shot on the YouTube video.